# How do I use 'useEffect' in React 18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, use-effect

I'm following a youtube tutorial, and the tutorial is using React 17 and I'm using React 18.  I'm at a section where we're formatting some animated text, everything is working OK, but the part I'm on is setting the letters  of the sentence to change on hover.  I'm getting the following error:

react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: useEffect must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up. You returned: 2

Here's the snip of code that is giving me issues:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return setTimeout(() => {
      setLetterClass('text-animate-hover')
    }, 4000)
  }, [])
```

Here is my scss for the text-animate-hover class:

```
  .text-animate-hover {
    min-width: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    animation-fill-mode: both;

    &:hover {
      animation: rubberBand 1s;
      color: #ffd700;
    }
  }
```

I'm reading that I don't need to use 'useEffect' with React 18, but I'm not understanding what I should be doing instead. Most of the searching I've done has returned a lot of instances using 'useEffect' with 'async' issues, which I'm having trouble relating those to my specific issue.

I appreciate any help with this.

-N8

Comment: This is not related to react 18 specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return` is incorrect in `useEffect`. `return` is designated for a clean-up function that runs when the component is unmounted. Make sure to `clearTimeout` in the clean-up otherwise `setLetterClass` will attempt to set state on an unmounted component, triggering a console error -

```
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const t = setTimeout(
        () => {
          setLetterClass('text-animate-hover');
        },
        4000
      );
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(t);
      }
    },
    [],
  );
```

You can read more about useEffect here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Thank you Mihail, that is SUPER helpful.  This has be stressing me out for a while.  Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, happy learning. :)

Answer (score 6):

You should always clear the timeout or any interval on component unmount.

```
useEffect(() => {
 let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    setLetterClass("text-animate-hover");
  }, 4000);

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is not the return. Because in the tutorial from Slobodan he is actually intending to run this when the component unmounts. Unfortunately this is not possible with React 18 anymore and neither running thing only once when the component mounts, because in React 18 useEffect actually runs twice since the component mount twice as well. with a simple console.log inside of a useEffect you can see what happens.

WRONG React 18 approach. Test:

```js
const MyTestComponent = () => {
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('component mounted') //This will actually output twice.
  },[])
  return <div>test component</div>
}
```

CORRECT React 18 approach. Actual code:

```
const About = () => {
 const [letterClass, setLetterClass] = useState('text-animate')
 const mountFlag = useRef(false) //here I am creating a flag

 useEffect(() => {
  if (!mountFlag.current) { //using the flag to check if component mounted
   mountFlag.current = true //updating flag
   setTimeout(() => {
    setLetterClass('text-animate-hover')
   }, 3000)
  }
 }, [])

 return <div>Component</div>
}
```

This is actually a problem of version and very common one by the way. The reason this happens it's because Slobodan made his tutorial using a different version of React. I encourage everyone to revise documentations about this issue since it will definitely break a lot of people's new apps.

Here we can see David Khourshid talking about it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPoC-k7Rxwo